# how can I make a whole program a variable the first time its ran and make another variable the second time and compare them both?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, updates

Im doing a web scraping program at the moment and it scrapes an info table every 5 mins and thats it. It prints the same table over an over, but what I want to do is compare the first time its run and name that 'num1', and compare it to the next time its run to see if any updates has occurred to the table. We could label this 'num2', I think I would need to label the first output in the terminal and compare it to the second time etc. and do something like:

```
if num1 != num2:
    print("updated")
```

but then I would need to compare 'num2' to 'num3' and so on....
Heres what I have so far:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request as request
import libxml2

totalurl = "https://www.icc-ccs.org/index.php/piracy-reporting-centre/live-piracy-report"
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(totalurl)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
source = html.fromstring(htmltext.decode())
num = source.xpath('//div[@class="fabrikDataContainer"]')
print(num[0].text_content())
```

Comment: Are you executing this script periodically, or do you plan to execute the script once and let it run as a background process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Performing periodic comparison of scraping results

If you want to periodically execute the script using something like `cron`, then what you can do is save the scraping results to a text file and simply load the text file on the next execution to compare for changes.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request as request
import libxml2

totalurl = "https://www.icc-ccs.org/index.php/piracy-reporting-centre/live-piracy-report"
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(totalurl)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
source = html.fromstring(htmltext.decode())
num = source.xpath('//div[@class="fabrikDataContainer"]')
print(num[0].text_content())
with open('lastresult.txt', 'r+') as f:
    last_content = f.read()
    if num[0].text_content() != last_content:
        print("updated")
    # update last result file
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(num[0].text_content())
    f.truncate()
```

### Addressing encoding problems

The reason why the comparison between the new content and last content is always returning true would seem to be related to the encoding as encoding the strings before performing the comparison and saving to the file works. The correct file open modes are then ‘rb+’ and ‘wb’ since you are writing bytes to the file, not strings.

```
import os
import urllib
import urllib.request as request
#import libxml2
from lxml import html

totalurl = "https://www.icc-ccs.org/index.php/piracy-reporting-centre/live-piracy-report"
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(totalurl)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
source = html.fromstring(htmltext.decode())
num = source.xpath('//div[@class="fabrikDataContainer"]')
new_content = str.encode(num[0].text_content(), 'utf8')
# print(new_content.decode('utf8'))
if os.path.exists('lastresult.txt'):
    with open('lastresult.txt', 'rb+') as f:
        last_content = f.read()
        if new_content != last_content:
            print("updated")
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(new_content)
        f.truncate()
else:
    with open('lastresult.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(new_content)
```

Note: I switched to lxml so I did not have to install libxml2 for python3 which is not available from the standard Ubuntu 16.04 repositories.

Comment: `open` with `r+` will return you `FileNotFoundError` if file not exists... You might need to add file existence verification. Something like `if not os.path.exists(lastresult.txt): code_to_create_empty_file`

Comment: It seems to be working, I think, but every time I run the program it prints "updated", when nothing has been updated in the text. @Andersson

Comment: ^^^^^ @cojomojo

Comment: also once the program is then saved again as last 'result.txt' again, it adds the current output to the original one. I want to compare the original with the 2nd. then 2nd with the 3rd, and then 3rd to 4th and so on. at the moment it will compare 1st to 2nd. Then 1st+2nd to 3rd and so on. so of course it will print "updated" because the latest time ran cannot equal all the times ran before all added together. @Andersson

Comment: @K.Blemings, that is how `r+` works. Try `w+` instead

Comment: Yeh I've tried that but it keeps printing "updated", when it hasn't?? @Andersson

Comment: @K.Blemings I updated the answer so that you will rewrite the file rather than append to it. @Andersson I believe `w+` will result in the file immediately be overwritten upon opening, so i think `r+` is still the solution.

Comment: it still prints updated when nothing has changed on the 2nd run from the 1st run. @cojomojo

Comment: @K.Blemings OK, I updated the answer again, and I verified that it works. It appears that an encoding problem was the issue.